# Add increments of 10 to a select query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to get target values (which needs to be auto incremented by 10, starting from 0) in SQL along with the results that I am already fetching in my Query.

Basically it needs to be a logic like:

```
set @target =0
```

and in my display query:

```
display -> @target = @target +10
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should edit your question and show your query (or a simplified version thereof).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you require permanently in the table then we can add identity column with increment as 10,

```
ALTER TABLE tablename add colname int identity(0,10)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want a column that increments by 10, use `row_number()`:

```
select (10 * (row_number() over (order by (select null)) )) as count_10
from t;
```

If you have an `order by` in your query, you should use the same `order by` for `row_number()`.